# Are O-planes not dynamical?

Tags: string-theory, branes

In Polchinski's book "String theory", he is saying "Unlike the case of D-branes, there are no string modes tied to the orientifold plane to represent fluctuations in its shape. Our heuristic argument that a gravitational wave forces a D-brane to oscillate does not apply to the orientifold plane. Essentially, the identifications (8.8.3) become boundary conditions at the fixed plane, such that the incident and reflected waves cancel. For the D-brane, the reflected wave is higher order in the string coupling."
I want know how to check "For O-plane,the incident and reflected waves cancel. For the D-brane, the reflected wave is higher order in the string coupling." Is there any papers or books or Web sites calculating it?